# cmake subproject dependency

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following file structure:

```
project
    folder1
        generator
        ...
    folder2
        sub
        ...
```

In `project` there is a CMakeLists.txt file:

```
add_subdirectory(folder1)
add_subdirectory(folder2)
```

Subproject `generator` creates a `required.cpp` for `sub`.
In `sub` I managed to build only after `required.cpp` is generated:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT required.cpp
        PRE_BUILD
        COMMAND generate...
        COMMENT "Generating..."
)

add_custom_target(run ALL DEPENDS required.cpp)
```

How can I assure that `generator` is built before trying to build `sub`? Or that `folder1` is built before `folder2`?

Comment: Just create target-level dependencies using [add_dependencies](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_dependencies.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `generator` is a target, then make target `run` depend on `generator` using

```
add_dependencies(run generator)
```

See the cmake documentation for [add_dependencies](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/add_dependencies.html) for details.